# missing link after nodes contracted with networkx

Tags: python, networkx

I've noticed that after two nodes are merged, a weird behavior occurs with some of the links. I've tested 2 scenarios, 1) with 3 nodes; 2) with 4 nodes.

**Scenario1**

```
G1 = nx.Graph()

G1.add_node(1,name='r1')
G1.add_node(2,name='r2')
G1.add_node(3,name='n1') 

G1.add_edges_from([(1,2),(2,3),(1,3)])

nx.write_graphml(G1,'G1.graphml')
```

The previous produces this network:

[image]

After that, I'm merging together nodes `r1` and `r2`. My expectation was that node `n1` would have 2 links towards `r1` but that does not happen.

Note: in order to be able to generate the `graphml` file, I had to remove the `contration` attribute from node `r1`.

```
G2 = nx.contracted_nodes(G1,1,2)

In [342]: G2.nodes(data=True)                                                                           
Out[342]: NodeDataView({1: {'name': 'r1', 'contraction': {2: {'name': 'r2'}}}, 3: {'name': 'n1'}})

del G2.nodes[1]['contraction']

In [345]: G2.nodes(data=True)                                                                           
Out[345]: NodeDataView({1: {'name': 'r1'}, 3: {'name': 'n1'}})

nx.write_graphml(G2,'G2.graphml')
```

[image]

**Scenario2**

But, if the network has more than 3 nodes, there is no missing link.

```
G3 = nx.Graph()

G3.add_node(1,name='r1')              
G3.add_node(2,name='r2')
G3.add_node(3,name='n1') 
G3.add_node(4,name='n2') 

G3.add_edges_from([(1,2),(2,3),(3,4),(4,1)])

nx.write_graphml(G3,'G3.graphml')
```

[image]

After this, again we merge nodes `r1` and `r2`.

```
G4 = nx.contracted_nodes(G3,1,2, self_loops=True)
G4.nodes(data=True)
del G4.nodes[1]['contraction']
nx.write_graphml(G4,'G4.graphml')
```

[image]

**Epilogue**

My idea was to be able to merge two nodes, such as `r1` and `r2` but still keep both of the original links, such as:

[image]

Any hint?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using a networkx `Graph`.  So the graph only has at most one edge per pair of nodes.  It also does not have direction to its edges.

If you want multiple edges for a pair of nodes, use a `MultiGraph`.  If you also want direction, use a `MultiDiGraph`.